# Hover over <span> and have a <div> display?

Tags: css

Here is what I am currently doing.

PHP echo's out the recent post in the database for a username with:

```
echo '<div id="userblock">test</div>';
echo '<span class="userpost">' . $str . ' - posted by <b>' . $username . '</b></span><br /><br />';
```

I then want to have it so when the test is hovered over you see the users profile/stats/information appear directly to the left of the post.

Here is what I have for CSS so far and I am in no way shape or form good at styling. So I would love your input.

```
div#userblock {
display:none;
}

span.userpost:hover  div#userblock {
    background-color:#efefef;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Try `#userblock{display:none;} .userpost:hover #userblock{display:block;}` as css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/sT66P/1/

**Jquery Code:**

```
$('.userpost').hover(function(){
    $(this).prev("#userblock").show();
    //$(this).prev("#userblock").toggle(); //if you want to toggle show/hide of div//
});​
```

**CSS Code**

```
#userblock {
 background:#999;
 display:none;
}

.userpost{
    background-color:#efefef;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

For that `#userblock` must be nested within `.userpost`.

Something like..

```
echo '<span class="userpost"> <div id="userblock".. />  </span>';
```

And then use the following CSS:

```
#userblock {

    display:none;
}

.userpost:hover  #userblock {

    display:block;
}
```